# Listing files from a remote URL using Java

Tags: java, url

I would like to list the files in a certain URL that requires authentication.
Note that I have no access to the FTP server.
Is there any possible way that I can do this using Java?

Comment: If you have *no access*, how are you going to list files? With java or not?

Comment: @MightyPork I'm guessing the user will enter the username and password.

Comment: @MightyPork I have access to the directory listing but not the FTP like this: http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/dixin/image_1D2FB4DA.png

Comment: @tbodt Yes the user will enter the username and password. So any ideas?

Comment: I'm writing an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing FTP from java is at best an arduous task, because the standard library doesn't provide anything for it. However, there are a few ways. There are three way to read directory listings, explained on [nsftools](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/JavaFtp.htm):

- Write your own class to talk to the FTP server. This is very compicated, and there are already such classes.
- Use the `sun.net.ftp.FTPClient` class. This class is used internally by the java library to download files from FTP, but it is undocumented, not guaranteed to be present in all java implementations, &c. Plus, directory listings are very hard to parse.
- Use the Jarkarta Net FTP library. This I think is the best option, but it has only one disadvantage: You need to supply the jar file as a dependency.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have no access to the FTP server.

Comment: That doesn't matter. You can in all cases specify a username and password at run time.

Comment: Can I use Apache Commons Net?

Comment: That's what I mean, they are the same thing. At least, I think so.